# MySQL Index on field with calculation

Tags: mysql, indexing

I can see in my Hosting server which one of my WordPress customers has installed a pluging with name of arrowchat,
That plugin is using the query below many many times,

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_users.ID userid, wp_users.display_name username, 
                arrowchat_status.session_time lastactivity, 
                wp_users.user_email avatar, wp_users.ID link, 
                arrowchat_status.message, arrowchat_status.status
    FROM wp_users
    JOIN arrowchat_status
        ON wp_users.ID = arrowchat_status.userid
    WHERE ('1391526259' - arrowchat_status.session_time - 60 < '120')
        AND wp_users.ID != 'g2192087'
```

using explain on MySQL shows that the arrowchat_status is being fetched by MySQL row by row ( all of it's rows ), even making index on arrowchat_status.session_time didn't help, but when I change the WHERE statement to below one, it only fetch 70 rows and runs so much faster.

```
WHERE (arrowchat_status.session_time >  '1391526319')
```

As these codes are not mine and I can't make changes to code of my client, is it possible to make some kind of Index in MySQL which help run the old query as fast as new one which I write? Kind of index that can be used in mathematical expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Such a feature indeed exists and is called *expression index* or *function based index*. However, MySQL doesn't support that.

Ref: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/math

The `!=` condition makes this really tough to index. A index on `(userid, session_time)` could still help if you'r running on 5.6+ (because of Index Condition Pushdown: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html).